# adicionar um foreing key em uma tabela já existente

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho que criar uma coluna em uma tabela existente e ao mesmo tempo criar uma foreing key com outra tabela utilizando esta coluna que foi criada, e esta foreing key por default tem que ser nulo. 
A forma que estou fazendo e esta

```
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSCOLUMNS C INNER JOIN SYSOBJECTS T ON C.id = T.id WHERE C.name = ('IdSetorPreparo') AND T.name = 'Produto')

    BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Produto  
            ADD IdSetorPreparo int     
    END 

    ALTER TABLE Produto 
        ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Produto_IdSetorPreparo FOREIGN KEY(IdSetorPreparo) REFERENCES OrgSetor(id)
```

Bom, queria saber se é possível ao mesmo tempo que criar a coluna ja criar a foreing key.

Comment: Sua tabela `Produto` já possui dados?

Answer (score 2):

No SQL Server podes fazer assim:

```
ALTER TABLE Produto
    ADD IdSetorPreparo INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(IdSetorPreparo) REFERENCES OrgSetor(id);
```

Se quiseres que a coluna admita NULOS apenas tens que a definir como NULL.

```
ADD IdSetorPreparo INTEGER NULL
```

Neste caso particular a *constraint* não será verificada.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajudar Bruno, conseguiu sanar minha duvida, se era possível criar a coluna e já setar um foreing key, muito obrigado.

Comment: Sem problema, ainda bem que pude ajudar!